# How to interop between DirectX11 in C++ with XAML&C# or should I turn to SharpXD

Tags: c#, c++, directx11, windows

I'm writing a UWP program and I want to write the general UI in C#. But there would be some graphic demonstrations using DirectX on some SwapChainPanels in the app. 
I have found less than enough documents of how I can interop between these two parts in two languages. And problem occurs such as how I should instance a C++ class from another project from C#.
I might need a frequent calling between the two part for the demonstration(It's actually a scatter plot). And some suggested that this could cause a great performance damage.
So should I turn to SharpXD? And what should I do if I don't.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is, don't. Because it is too complicated, and if the interop is frequent, it may cause performance problems. Use SharpDX instead. I found managed DirectX is much more clear and simpler, though currently the archives are not very complete.

Answer (score 0):

For XAML you have a choice of using C# or C++ code-behind. The base platform only supports C++ access to DirectX APIs, so the DirectX+XAML template is provided for C++, but not C#.

You can certainly use SharpDX or other C# wrappers to get C# assemblies DirectX, but you might also want to consider using [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) for something like a scatter plot.

Comment: It's a 3D scatter point actually. I found rescourses for SharpDX aren't that rare and I would give it a try.